# Mysql - union of 2 tables with different columns

Tags: mysql

I know the topic is already on other threads, but my problem is that i could not use union (table 1 has 60 columns; table 2 has only 7). Is there another way than creating for table 2 ...53 empty columns?

Is it possible to generate the result in one query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this by replacing non existent columns with nulls like below

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Null as Col4, Null as Col5 from Table2
```

Replace the columns in tables with null if the column does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, since you can add any number of arbitrary columns in a select:

```
select field1, field2, field3 from table1
union
select field4, null, field5 from table2
```

In the above example I used a constant null value as the 2nd field, but you can choise any value befitting the data type of the existing column in the other table.

Comment: Thank you. And how do i call the values from a certsin column ( first or second value(

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question!

Comment: I think i should rephrase it. First of all my problem is this: i have 2 tables which contain id (as relation) as primary key. I need to use a single query in order to find in both tsbles the same id (same object) which values to be inserted in the webpage (row[field]…). For this I guess i should open another thread. My previous question related to union was: if i use union, i understand i will have each column with 2 values? If yes, how do i call each of them? Or the values are simple concatenated into the field?

Comment: Yes, open a new question for the join. In case of union the values are placed "below" one another from the different tables. Let's take my sample code: values from field1 and field4 will appear in a single column below each other in separate rows, which will be called field1 in the resultset. To place data from multiple tables into a single field, you need to use join as opposed to union.